# prevent VS code notification: 'launch' is already running. Do you want to start another instance?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm writing an ui with tkinter (ttk), and if I run the my program while an other instance of the ui is open, VS code (starting today) started giving a (error) notification which looks like this:

[image: error notification]

I'm not sure but I think this started happening when I started using ttk (instead of only tkinter).
I know you're not meant to run multiple instances of your program, but while coding it's very convenient to be able to see what you're changing along the way, and not have to close your previous instance.

Is there a way to stop this notification of appearing?

Comment: I don't think there is any setting to disable that notification.  See issue (Give us settings to disable restart debugging modal confirmation dialog) https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/132201.  The vscode team member surely would have mentioned one if it were available.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a way to stop this notification of appearing?

VSCode 1.71 (August 2022) should offer an option for that.

See [issue 147912](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/147912) and [PR 147914](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/147914)

> Add new launch config debug option for silent `'{0}' is already running. Do you want to start another instance?` confirm dialog.
>
> Tested with simple launch config:
>
> ```yaml
> {
>    "command": "npm start",
>    "name": "Run npm start",
>    "request": "launch",
>    "type": "node-terminal",
>    "suppressMultipleSessionWarning": true
> }
> ```

This is available in [VSCode Insiders today](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/).

Comment: Great. Any ideas how to activate it? In merged PR thread they [agreed] (https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/147914#issuecomment-1197139016) on putting it in settings.json plus UI checkbox. Can't find it (v1.74).

Comment: @arthur I confirm this is not, and does not appear to be in the near future, supported as a global setting. This is still located only in a project `launch.json`.

Comment: Hm.. [Property multipleSessionWarning is not allowed]
From launch.json>Launch Targets> {} Python: Current File

Comment: @arthur Same on my `launch.json`, not sure why, and I cannot leave a comment on the issue or PR, whose conversations are closed.

Comment: Created another question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75291972/how-to-switch-off-confirmation-message-for-debug-console-in-visual-studio-code

Answer (score 2):

I bound F5 to restart, so i only have to run it once, and to see changes i restart that instance (changed run to F7)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Include this in your keybindings.json`{ "key": "f5", "command": "workbench.action.debug.restart" }`