# How to switch off confirmation message for debug console in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73256262/3074348) I know that it's possible to switch off confirmation message for debug console in Visual Studio Code after merging this [PR](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/147914). How to switch it ON? Switching `multipleSessionWarning` to False gives Property multipleSessionWarning is not allowed on in launch.json gives `[Property multipleSessionWarning is not allowed] From launch.json>Launch Targets> {} Python: Current File`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual [commit 960b783](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/147914/commits/960b78323c51f0dc2830e6d2aee50a616f40db55) which implemented the [PR 147914](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/147914) actually *renamed* the new setting, and reverse its logic:

From

```
"MultipleSessionWarning": false
```

To:

```
"suppressMultipleSessionWarning": true
```

That last setting 'suppressMultipleSessionWarning' does not trigger a "Property is not allowed" warning in a `launch.json`.

Comment: And I have [edited my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73256262/6309) accordingly.